# Cookie of an array won't set immediately on submit

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I use WP 4.4.1 and Genesis 2.2.5.
I have the following code in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpcd_set_cookie', 1 );

function wpcd_set_cookie() {
if(isset( $_POST[ 'opmerkingen' ] ) ) :
$cookie_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'opmerkingen' ] );
setcookie( 'opmerkingen', $cookie_value, time() + 604800, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN ); // 86400 = 1 day 604800 = 7 days
endif;

if(isset( $_POST[ 'items_aantal' ] ) ) :
$cookie_value = json_encode( $_POST[ 'items_aantal' ], true );
setcookie('items_aantal_cookie', $cookie_value, time() + 604800, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
endif;

}
```

Somehow, the set cookie process works fine (immediately on submit) for field "opmerkingen" (which is not an array) and later (after two posts) for field "items_aantal" (which is an array).

Can anybody help me out? I can't seem to get this working. Yet, I'm so close...

Thanks in advance.